# with ajax responce add new row in table

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am struggling to add new row in the table in asp.net MVC.

**view code:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    var tbody = $('.table tbody'), row;


    function availableDrivers() {
        if (typeof row == "undefined") {

            var actionUrl = '@Url.Action("GetAvailableDrivers", "Agency")';

            $.getJSON(actionUrl, displayData);
                function displayData(response) {
                    tbody.append(response.Html);
                    row = response.Html;
                };

        } else {
            //
            tbody.append(row);
        }
    }

    $('#addTableRow').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        availableDrivers();

    });});
```

AND Json comes back as:

```
Html :  <tr><select><option id='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'>Driver Name</option></select></tr>
```

so the question is, it doesnt catch the responce.html and doesn't appent onto table:

it does append if I do response.html[1], however appents only leter t.

any toughts are welcome

Comment: Do you have a class called table or it's a mistake in your code. selector should be $('table tbody')

Comment: yes, I have a class called table (bootstrap requirement)

Comment: Also can you please add closing "select" tag in your response and td tag surrounding of select tag.

Comment: yea, that's fixed now. however doesn't sort the main problem unfortunately.

Comment: also just noticed that JSON might be wrong.
'{"html":"\u003ctr\u003e\u003cselect\u003e\u003coption id=\u002700000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\u0027\'...  Where are the '<>' tags?

Comment: I have solved my self.

forgot to add <td></td> in the json response.